# How index content is generated in Octopress

Tags: liquid, octopress

TL;DWTR (Too Long; Don't Want To Read): I want to grab the first post of an Octopress blog and style it differently than the others, but I can't figure out how.

---

And so...

Using the basic template as a starting point, I've built a custom theme.

For the index page, where each post will be listed, I have the following:

```
{{ content | expand_urls: root_url }}
```

Then, I have another partial, _article_listing.html that renders each post summary with the links and everything.

What I don't understand is how the two are connected. How does {{ content }} know to {% include _article_listing.html %}?

There doesn't seem to be an intermediary partial or a for-loop or anything. Is it hard-coded somewhere?

Thank you. I hope the answer is blindingly obvious and I'll say "of course!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer. The for loop I was missing happens in /source/index.html

Why is that particular file outside the _layouts folder? Why isn't index.html where all {% includes %} happen? No idea.

Anyway, there it is.

Comment: To fully answer the question, here's how to grab the first post:

    {% if forloop.first %}

That was easy.

Answer (score 0):

This is defined by the `layout` property in your YAML front-matter. In layout files, `content` holds the rendered output of the page being wrapped in that layout.

`{{ content }}` doesn't include `_article_listing.html`, but may end up containing the rendered output of that include if the page itself has `{% include _article_listing.html %}` in it (or any of the other pages it includes).

Comment: But that's kind of my problem. Using a fresh install of octopress, I have the following line in default.html
{{ content | expand_urls: root_url }}